# 403 Forbidden Error on Post request after upgrade of macOS from BigSur to Monterey

Tags: spring-boot, postman, macos-monterey

I upgraded my macOS from BigSur to Monterey yesterday, and now I can not make POST requests in postman to my application. when I run `curl -i http://localhost:5000` I get a **403 Forbidden** error.

[image: Response Headers]

Environment:

- Postman Version 9.1.3 (9.1.3)
- Docker version 4.1.1
- Spring boot version 2.5.6

Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the `Server` line – it's not your application that is responding. See [Why is Control Center on Monterey listening on ports?](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332).

Answer (score 2):

This is because the “AirPlay Receiver” in  macOs Monterey uses port 5000.
so it can be fixed by **disabling AirPlay Receiver service from System preferences**. Check this post for more info https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332